# How do I remove shared documents & folders that I have in My Drive in Google Apps?

Tags: google-drive

I recently added a shared folder to My Drive using the option 'Add to My drive'. How do I remove it from My Drive?

Although am unsure whether this is the proper way of doing it but if I check the folder I want removed and then select 'Remove' it removes it. Google should really offer the option to 'Remove Shared Folder for My Drive'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said in your edit, you can simply remove (delete) the folder/file from your Google Drive to remove it from your own drive. This is equivalent to stopping Google from continuing to follow updates to that particular folder/file and showing it in your drive.

Answer (score 4):

I found an easy way for removing from My Drive, in a way that shows what is happening:

1. Select the file or folder
2. See its details by clicking on the "See Details" button: in "Location", all places where the item is are shown.
3. click on the "X" at the right of "My Drive"

This way I was able to see where I was removing the folder from, without frightening warnings.

Answer (score 1):

May I add the following:
If you synchronise your Google Drive on your PC, the shared folder will appear/synch on your PC drive;
**and do not** delete the shared folder you add on your Drive via your PC/windows explorer.
Instead **you must use** the *remove* function you have via the Google Drive web interface.